# Understanding why git auto merge keeps the older version of a line

Tags: git

We have a branch "sprintX" and a "master" branch, during our sprint we push to the sprint branch and at the end of the sprint, we merge it into master. A few times during the sprint we merge master into the branch for getting the hotfixes.

Today we try to merge master into our branch and we have multiple conflict on file that were not updated since the branch creation and the git auto merging keep the file from the master branch ie removing our new code into our sprint branch.

We would like to understand why is git resolving the conflict that way and how can we change our way of doing things for avoiding it ?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing something more specific.Conflicts aren't a bad thing...

Comment: @evolutionxbox: they are not bad, but it's very worrying when you see a change performed on branch X disappear on branch Y despite clearly being merged into X->Y, that indicates that someone did a revert or failed to properly merge files (i.e. had an old version and picked "choose mine everywhere", etc). This means that either the reverter-guy forgot to tell everybody (or he did not know it's important), or the merger-guy needs training (or sleep :) ). All of them worrying. I've seen it happening many times, and I've never seen GIT itself causing that..

Answer (score 2):

Most probably someone some time ago used a "revert" option to remove that line on the master branch, or any patch branch that was merged to master, but not to your current sprintX. In this case, "master" branch knows that it was changed and then undone, and thinks that the old version is the correct one, while your sprintX has not seen the revert and thinks that the new version is the correct one. Bam! Conflict.

Go to **master** branch and **carefully** check the history of this file. Check that line and see when it was changed back/forth between new and old version. Look for any explicit "reverts" (commits named 'revert') or implicit (someone simply edited the file back to old form) or reverts-by-uncareful-merge (someone did a merge that overwrote the line with old version). Really. All of that. It's because "revert" option is just a commit. There is nothing special about it. It could be a direct revert, or accidental, and the things I just listed ae the most common things that force a branch to have an old-version-of-something.

Then, knowing where it happened on master, check history around that places, and try to guess why that person (who did it the revert) did not include it in sprintX

Comment: you are right ! I needed to display the full log, because a "reverte merge" was commit so the version with the old code is seen as newer by git :( we'll have to work on our reverting strategy